# Select query on multiple tables multiple times

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables: `COMMENTS` and `USERS`. I save user's name on `COMMENTS` table, but user's avatar details should be taken from `USERS` table.

```
SELECT c.id, c.tarih, c.yorum, c.yorumcu, 
(SELECT avatarID FROM USERS WHERE Username=c.yorumcu) AS avatarID 
FROM COMMENTS c WHERE c.id = ?
```

The question mark at the end gets replaced with `NEWS_ID`. (e.g `news.php?id=5`)

I managed to code this, but it only gets the "last comment" details from database, not all of them. (Let's say 5 people commented on page, it only gets the last (5th) comment, ignoring the rest.)

Can anybody help me?

Ps. Yorumcu means "Commenter". `COMMENTS.Commenter` and `USERS.Username` are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should your WHERE clause not be "WHERE c.news_id = ?", rather than "WHERE c.id = ?" ? I am assuming that c.id is unique to each comment.

Comment: I feel stupid now. Thanks alot. I was checking comment ID instead of news_id. Were about to go crazy...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select c.id, c.tarih, c.yorum, c.yorumcu, avatarID 
FROM COMMENTS,USERS 
where USERS.Username=c.yorumcu  and c.id = ?
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. The query above worked like a charm after I change c.id to c.news_id.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that COMMENTS.id is the unique identifier for the table COMMENTS?

If that is the case, it is logic, that you only get returned 1 comment.

Do you have a identifier for NEWSID in the COMMENTS table?
Then you should use this one to retrieve multiple comments.